# Cannot save data --- Swift, IOS, Core data --- Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, save, sigabrt

output:

> 2018-05-08 10:43:35.852689-0400 PatientRecord[37013:6040121] [error]
>   error:  Failed to load model named PatientRecord CoreData: error: 
>   Failed to load model named PatientRecord 2018-05-08
>   10:43:35.864686-0400 PatientRecord[37013:6040121] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter
>   searching for entity name 'Patient''

My breakpoints indicate that it crashes on: `let entity = NSEntityDescription`...

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class CoreDataHandler: NSObject {

private class func getContext() -> NSManagedObjectContext{

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate

    return appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext

}

class func saveObject(onset: String, name: String, headache: String) -> Bool {

    let context = getContext()
    let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Patient", in: context)
    let manageObject = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertInto: context)

    manageObject.setValue(onset, forKey: "onset")
    manageObject.setValue(name, forKey: "name")
    manageObject.setValue(headache, forKey: "headache")

    do{
        try context.save()
        return true
    }catch{
        return false
    }
}

class func fetchObject() -> [Patient]? {
    let context = getContext()
    var patient:[Patient]? = nil
    do{
        patient = try context.fetch(Patient.fetchRequest())
        return patient
    }catch{
        return patient
    }
}


}
```

**main class**

```
import UIKit
//import CoreData

class AbdominalPainViewController: ViewController {

 var patient:[Patient]? = nil

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    CoreDataHandler.saveObject(onset: "OnsetLabeltext", name: "PatientNLabelext", headache: "woo")

        patient = CoreDataHandler.fetchObject()

        for i in patient! {
            print(i.name!)
        }

}
}
```

Not sure what im doing wrong, this exact code works in a different project, with the same entity name. Thank you for your help :)

EDIT:
[image]

Comment: Pls show us what's in your `.xcdatamodel`?

Comment: I've added the picture in the edit

Answer (score 0):

Pls try to prefix the class name in the Class field of the model entity inspector with the name of your module, just like this: `"PatientRecord.Patient"` 
more info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) stated

> To configure a Swift subclass of NSManagedObject for use by a Core
>   Data model entity, open the model entity inspector in Xcode, enter the
>   class name into the Class field, and choose “Current Product Module”
>   from the Module field drop-down list.

Comment: still same issue :(